# How to identified given string is double byte characterset using java?

Tags: java, encoding, double-byte

I want to Identify given string is double byte character set or not, using java?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `String` does not have a character set property, in fact, it is always [UTF-16](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.4) (16 bit used for each char).

Comment: I think you mean that it's always UTF-16 (though that doesn't always mean that 16 bits is used for each character either)

Comment: @Adam Batkin - yes, my mistake, changed it already and linked it to the java language spec.

Comment: I have a text field in which a user can enter data in chinese,japanese,English or Korean Languages. So we need to figure out a way to read these double byte characters.

Comment: @sam the text field will store the character in a *"double byte"* `String` internally. If conversion is needed from a charset to UTF-16, then the component will take care of it. *You* get a `String` in UTF-16 from the textfield.

Comment: @Andreas_D, you might find the -XX:+UseCompressedStrings option interesting. ;) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to try to discover the likely charset of some input data (e.g. in a file or stream), then the [ICU4J CharsetDetector](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CharsetDetector.html) could be used.

But by the time the data is in a String in your code, it is too late.

Answer (score 0):

Your string has multibyte characters if `String.codePointCount(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` for the whole text range will give not zero result.